# Symfony 3.1 installation cURL error 60

Tags: curl, symfony

Im using Windows 10, Wamp and I am trying to install symfony framework, but have this problem :
Im following official symfony setup documentation.(https://symfony.com/download)
At first I had problems with PHP not being enviromental variable, but i fixed that.

Now I can without errors use this line :

```
php -r "file_put_contents('symfony', file_get_contents('https://symfony.com/installer'));"
```

it creates file named symfony.

After that I try to use

```
php symfony new my_project
```

but This returns:

> [GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\RingException]   cURL error 60: SSL
>   certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

To fix this I tried :

I downloaded cacert.pem file from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and saved this file in C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.19\extras\ssl

after that I changed php.ini file where i changed line

> ;curl.cainfo=

to

> curl.cainfo ="C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.19\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"

but after using     `php symfony new my_project`

I get the same error again. I tried to restart cmd, wamp and pc nothing helps.

Anything I did wrong or didnt notice?

Comment: Did you change the OPENSSL value too in the php.ini ? This article could help you : http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/196/xampp-wampp-php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate , i faced this problem a couple of weeks ago and it works now, remember to restart the services after you make the change.

Comment: Thanks, I havent done that.. In the end I fixed my problem which was - I was changing php.ini file by clicking on wamp icon->php->php.ini. (which I thought was php.ini file in my php installation dirrection but actually it is phpForApache.ini)